# How to fix the "'str' object has no attribute 'META'" error?

Tags: python, django, python-2.5

I have a Django application with following model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

There is a URL, which should display `Topic`'s details:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    [...]
    (r'^topic/(\d+)$', 'history_site.views.topic_details'),
    [...]
)
```

`history_site.views.topic_details` is defined as

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context, RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
import logging
from opinions.models import Topic
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

logging.basicConfig(filename='history-site.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

def topic_details(request, topic_id_string):
    topic_id = int(topic_id_string)
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    return TemplateResponse('topic.tpl.html', locals())
```

`topic.tpl.html` has following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% block prehtml %}
{% endblock %}

<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ topic.title }} </h1>


{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to access the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/topic/1` I get the error `'str' object has no attribute 'META'`.

Why?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you include the code of the error please?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres You can find the traceback here - http://dpaste.com/1257647/ .

Comment: I did put an answer that has to fix yor problem :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects)

```
TemplateResponse.__init__(request, template, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, current_app=None)
```

the first parameter TemplateResponse takes is a request not a template name

so your code is wrong, try to change it for something like:

```
return TemplateResponse(request, 'topic.tpl.html', locals())
```